# Pause button position in a game UI?

Tags: layout

I see them mostly at the top left and top right of the screen (touchscreen games).

Which is better, and why?

Comment: This will usually be based on the mechanics of the game and if any other functions exist.  Usually a location will have restart, pause, exist, panel navigation etc. etc.  Some even have a pause game in a drop down panel to free up the in game experience.

Comment: There is not an answer, beyond personal opinion, that can answer this question as written. Your game design will guide where a potential pause button will go (maybe you shouldn't have a pause button at all).

Comment: Is there an answer beyond personal opinion to any aspect of UX design?

Comment: @Confused - Yes. If you're unsure how that works, please investigate more in [what UX design is](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/05/what-is-user-experience-design-overview-tools-and-resources/), and [what it involves](http://www.helloerik.com/ux-is-not-ui).

Comment: a cursory glance at the first link reveals this argument against your claim: "Evaluating the effectiveness and return on investment of a UX design using quantitative measures is difficult. This is because the field is subjective."

Comment: And there's nothing in the second link that argues against the entire field being subjective. But many points support the notion.

Comment: If you wish to take one sentence from an extensive article pointing out all the aspects of UX (Human Factors, Ergonomics, Accessibility, all very *not* subjective) and take the "how users feel about it" aspect as the overriding factor, you will continue to have trouble in developing a truly usable and useful interface. You can also look into the many resources it links to, for learning all the qualitative methods involved. If you're unsure how the majority of the steps illustrated in the second article are not at all subjective, I would suggest looking into those more as well.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be best served reading up on what the words subjective and objective actually mean, and the word 'field'.

Comment: If wish to maintain a faulty view of what UX involves and talk down to experienced people trying to point you to resources to help you see what all is involved in creating "good design", that's unfortunate.

Comment: Perhaps I'm more experienced than you. Consider that for a moment. Then another. Because that's an objective truth. As for your comment about "talk down", I'll leave you with this quote from you: "you will continue to have trouble in developing a truly usable and useful interface." An odd assumption and very pointed and misplaced attempt at aggression and condescension.

Comment: btw this: "from an extensive article pointing out all the aspects of UX" is an incorrect use of the words "all" and "extensive". The article was neither.

Answer (score 1):

From the minimal amount of information I would say; roughly 90% of people are right handed, therefore will likely be using the phone with their right hand. If pausing is an important/prevalent part of the game put the button in the top right to be easier to reach. If you have more important elements or if the pause button is going to block important game real estate move it to the left as to leave room for more important things in the right side.

Comment: What's the most popular game on iOS and Android that features a pause button? Where is it located?

Comment: Throughout the history of gaming, what has the top left side and top middle of the screen been typically used for the presentation of?

Answer (score 1):

The same depends on what your rest of the controls are, or in other words which hand you would be using the most while playing the game.

If the game can be placed by just one hand, placing it on the right makes a lot of sense as most of the users are right handed.

If the game needs to you use both your hand to control, the pause button should be placed towards the one hand which is assumed to be less busy.

For example, in a game where you have to use your left hand to steer the car, and the right hand to fire the boost, placing the pause button on the right makes much more sense.